# How to persist data with toggleable state in Redux

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux, state

I have a `TOGGLE_SAVED` action in my reducer that I want to both toggle the `saved` property on a target "image" object (within a `loadedImages` array), as well as store that object in a `savedImages` array in state.

I only want one image object in the current `loadedImages` array to have `saved` be true as I expect `loadedImages` to repopulate upon some GET request, while keeping the saved image from the last request in `savedImages`

Right now my code looks as so:

```
const initialState = {
    loadedImages: [],
    savedImages: [],
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOAD_IMAGES:
            return {
                ...state, 
                loadedImages: action.payload, // payload returns a fetch(...)[]
            }
        case TOGGLE_SAVED:
            return {
                ...state,
                loadedImages: state.loadedImages.map(img => {
                    if (img.id === action.payload.id) {

                        return {...img, saved: !img.saved}

                    } else {
                        return {...img, saved: false}
                    }

                }),

                savedImages: [
                    ...state.loadedImages.filter(img => img.saved)
                ]
            } 

        default: 
            return state
    }
}
```

Right now, `savedImages` is only populated when `TOGGLE_SAVED` is ran twice and items within `savedImages` do not persist over, every time `loadedImages` is repopulated (via GET request).

Note: a typical "image" object is returned in payload as: 
`{id: 0, saved: Boolean}`

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your current reducer, the `savedImages` prop is actually using the previous reference to `loadedImages`.

That's why it only works on the second run. You assume that the initial `loadedImages` `map()` runs and completes, and then moves on to the next prop, but that is not the case.

What could work is something like this:

```
case TOGGLE_SAVED:

            const loadedImages = state.loadedImages.map(img => {
                if (img.id === action.payload.id) {
                    return {...img, saved: !img.saved}
                } else {
                    return {...img, saved: false}
            })

            return {
                ...state,
                loadedImages,

                savedImages: [
                    ...loadedImages.filter(img => img.saved)
                ]
            }
```